# Mount a volume to a container expanded variable

Tags: docker

How can I mount a volume to a path set by an environment variable in the container.

For example say `FOO=/foo` is an environment variable available in the container. I'd like to mount `foo.conf` to the `$FOO` directory in the container. Something like

```
docker run -v foo.conf:$FOO/foo.conf ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's impossible to do it via `volumes`. But you can utilize bash linking.

Specify a static directory into which the foo.conf will always be mapped to (inside container) like:

```
$ docker run -v foo.conf:/usr/src/app/foo.conf ...
```

and then link this file to the location you desire:

```
$ ln -sv /usr/src/app/foo.conf $FOO/
```

If you want to `link` it in build time, you have to define the env variable in build time and only then try accessing it. Otherwise you might setup a `entrypoint` with this linking command or run it manually if it's not a problem.